# How do I turn an image (200x200 Black and White photos) into a single list of 40,000 values using numpy?

Tags: numpy, image-processing

As the title says I have an image (well a bunch of images) and I want to turn it from a 200x200 image into a 1-D list of 40,000.

Comment: In general, readers welcome questions that appear to be thoroughly researched. I can't help with Numpy, but I imagine it has a manual, and that you will have tried a few things. Are you able to edit the question with this detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to flatten the image and convert it to list.

```
 img.ravel().tolist()
```

A ndarray of shape Nx200x200 can be converted by reshaping

```
bunch_of_images.reshape(N, 40000)
```

Comment: What do you want to know more about it? I have a data set of a bunch of images and i wanted to use scikit learn on them. I was reading that my data can't be 3d if plan to use scikit learn (I have a set images, and each image is 200x200 making it 3d). That's why I want to turn the 200x200 part into 40k

Comment: What is img.shape?

Comment: @somedude1234 :200×200 is 2D indeed. 200×200×3 is 3D

Comment: @tstanisl so for my code I opened up my file using PIL and then what do i do from there? I can't call .ravel() on it

Comment: @somedude1234 you can covert PIL image to array with np.array(pil_image)

Comment: okay thanks! I got it thanks for all your help